# log4j how to append blank line

Tags: java, log4j

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Log4J print empty line to logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843941/log4j-print-empty-line-to-logfile)

In java, I can use `System.out.println()` to print a blank line.

And now I  want to know how to log a blank line in log4j.

Is there any method named `logger.appendEmptyLine()` or any method that can do this?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11843941/1515052

Comment: This question was asked on May 10, the "duplicate" linked by @Simulant was asked on August 7. So the duplicate was asked after this question. Now which one is the duplicate really? So much for `as earlier questions on this topic`.

Comment: this one was erlier, but I found it later. I didn't want to answer the same text on both questions. An the other User who asked the Question is more active.

Answer (score 0):

```
logger.debug("\n");
```

or maybe

```
logger.debug("");
```

Comment: That will break the message.  I'm assuming he wants the date/time stamp to be immediately before the message, but have a blank line or two before the that log message.