# What does stringBuffer.append("\n") mean?

Tags: java

I was just looking though some code and I came across this line:

```
stringBuffer.append("\n");
```

can anyone tell me what it means? Or more specifically what the "\n" part does?

Thanks

Comment: It appends (adds to the end of, in this case, the string contained in stringBuffer) a `new line` character. You may need to go over a basic tutorial, it would be in there.

Comment: So the \n means new line basically? Or tells the stringBuffer to go to the next line?

Comment: Yes, the `"\n"` means new line. It's easier to remember, rather than the ASCII code for adding a new line.

Comment: I would prefer `System.lineseparator()` in such situations where you are building a String.  `\n` is a system specific new line marker that might not work on all systems.

Comment: @Airglow. When you add "\n" to Stringbuffer , it is just converted in to corresponding byte as other character does. But when display the characters in some editor/console , the bytes from String would convert into shapes based on ASCII/ Charset choosed. In Most of the charset ( in my mind 100%) would result next line for the byte equivalent to the '\n' .  These are special instructions to the machine to do tab space line feed CR and so.

Comment: @demongolem Is there a system that "\n" wouldn't work on? I thought it was a standard that the JVM would always interpret as newline.

Comment: @AntonH At least with StringBuilder this is the case, I am not 100% sure of StringBuffer.  Like maybe you need `\r\n` or something of that sort.

Comment: Newline will not work in log4j logging if you just add newline to the message and try to put it into the log. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843941/log4j-print-empty-line-to-logfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"\n" means line breaking, in the following example the output will be

a
b

ex code:

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
stringBuffer.append("a");
stringBuffer.append("\n");
stringBuffer.append("b");
System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Adds `new line` marker to text that is actually in StringBuffer. Next part will be shown in the line below.

Answer (score 2):

It appends a "newline" character, thus ending the current line and beginning a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You can read what `\n` and other characters mean in the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html):

*A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has special meaning to the compiler. The following table shows the Java escape sequences:*
...
*`\n`   Insert a newline in the text at this point.*

Answer (score 1):

`\n` is a new line character.  Here is an example:

```
System.out.print("hello\nmy\nname\nis\ntyler\n");
```

Outputs:

```
hello
my
name
is
tyler
```