# Java loggers do not start messages from new line sometimes

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Is there any way to fix such behaviour?

**Examples:**
[image: example one]

[image: example two]

In the log files everything is okay, but in the tool that shows the logfiles some lines are like this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is quite unclear. Can you provide an example? What loggers? Where is the new line missing? Only in the console? In log files, too? 

If it's only in the console, I would guess that two (or more) objects are writing to the console (for example, you are doing `System.out.print(...)`additionally to the logging), which can mess up your output, of course.

Comment: Can you post where your logger is defined? xml maybe?

Comment: too hard to explain without showing companie's code which I can not do. Will go find help in some better place.

Comment: @maxpovver Feel free to post an answer if you do solve it. Without the full context of the problem any answer would be something of a guess. Providing the details requested by Florian would help narrow it down.

Comment: I'd guess the next question is "what tool are you using to view the logfiles?". If the log files themselves are fine, I don't think it's a log4j problem.

Comment: I got that already. but I can't delete this qiuestion now... @Edd

Answer (score 2):

`Log4j` is designed to write what you give to it... no `println` function.

So you must add it to your log message `+ "\n"` or create a `FileAppender` that adds new line in each log entry.

[Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11845422/3850595)

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is incorrect. The linked question does not appear to be about what you think it's about - that wanted additional, completely blank, lines to be inserted in the log file. You shouldn't have to append a newline character onto the end of your log messages, at least not with a standard-ish configuration.

Comment: "So you must add it to your log message + "\n" "
seriously? the logger must care about it itself when we use .info() / .debug() functions. and usually it does, but fails sometimes without obvious reason

Comment: @Jordi Castilla is almost correct. To add a new line automatically after a log message your patternLayout pattern value needs to be something like `pattern="%m%n"`. The `%n` is what sets the new line, `\n` might also work but is not exactly the log4j2 config way.

Comment: to do a blank line between each message simply use `pattern="%m%n%n"`